# On Cardinalities of $\mathcal{RE}$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: computability

We denote $\mathcal{RE}$ as the universe set of recursively enumerable sets. A set is recursively enumerable iff its semi-charactersitic function is computable (one can write its semi-verifier). The question is, can we build a bijection between $\mathcal{RE}$ and the powerset of naturals?

Comment: Obviously not, since a set is r.e. iff it is the domain of a Turing Machine.

Comment: Please remind that I mention the set of all recursive enumerable sets, not a set that is in $\mathcal{RE}$.

Comment: There are only countably many Turing machines, so there are only countably many r.e. sets.

Answer (score 2):

There are only countably many sets in $\mathcal{RE}$ and there are uncountably many sets in $P(\mathbb{N})$, so we cannot build a bijection between $\mathcal{RE}$ and $P(\mathbb{N})$. (This is a community-wiki answer so that the question is not marked as unanswered.)